# JTextField как вводить только числа?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

Как сделать так, чтобы в `JTextField` можно было вводить только цифры?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Делается это при помощи `DocumentFilter`

```
class DigitFilter extends DocumentFilter {
    private static final String DIGITS = "\\d+";

    @Override
    public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int offset, String string, AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {

        if (string.matches(DIGITS)) {
            super.insertString(fb, offset, string, attr);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String string, AttributeSet attrs) throws BadLocationException {
        if (string.matches(DIGITS)) {
            super.replace(fb, offset, length, string, attrs);
        }
    }
}
```

После этого вы должны назначить этот фильтр для поля

```
JTextField textField = new JTextField();

PlainDocument doc = (PlainDocument) textField.getDocument();
doc.setDocumentFilter(new DigitFilter());
```