# Java.Swing.как запретить вводить цифры или буквы в какое-либое текстовое поле?

Tags: java, swing

Необходимо запретить ввод чего либо в какое-либо текстовое поле Swing

Answer (score 2):

Вот пример, как вводить только числа,
скопирован с [JTextField как вводить только числа?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/628341/jtextfield-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0)

Делается это при помощи DocumentFilter

```
class DigitFilter extends DocumentFilter {
    private static final String DIGITS = "\\d+";

    @Override
    public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int offset, String string, AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {

        if (string.matches(DIGITS)) {
            super.insertString(fb, offset, string, attr);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String string, AttributeSet attrs) throws BadLocationException {
        if (string.matches(DIGITS)) {
            super.replace(fb, offset, length, string, attrs);
        }
    }
}
```

После этого вы должны назначить этот фильтр для поля

```
JTextField textField = new JTextField();

PlainDocument doc = (PlainDocument) textField.getDocument();
doc.setDocumentFilter(new DigitFilter());
```